# How to Create a Command to open an Application like Matlab in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: command-line, matlab

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I have installed MATLAB which is in `/usr/local/Matlab/R2018a/bin/matlab` I want to create a COMMAND (like `matlab`) in Terminal, so that I can open MATLAB after running that command (rather than using Desktop Launcher).

Checked all possible post available in Ask Ubuntu but cant executed. Please help if you have a proper solution.